# Multiple canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Necesito realizar una funcionalidad que por medio de un select pueda crear la misma cantidad de canvas, es decir, si en un select escogo cantidad "3", me cree 3 canvas

Comment: saludos Eduard, cuéntanos, ¿Qué has intentado? Te invito a dar una vuelta por http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que te familiarices con el sitio, así tendrás preguntas con mayor calidad y de la misma manera, obtendrás respuestas de mayor calidad. Bienvenido a SOes :D

Comment: Además de lo que te dice @fredyfx, consulta la guía [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
// bind change event to select
$('#marcas').on('change', function () {
    var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
     for(var i = 0;i < url;i++){
      $("#myDiv").append("<canvas height="100" width = "100" id = 'canvas-"+i+"' ></canvas>");
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: espero y te surva :D

Comment: em el div de #marcas es un select jajajajaj

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de mucho :)